# Swift, Label not refreshing while in callback function

Tags: swift, uilabel, dispatch-async

I want to change/reload my label on activity indicator while i am running on the loop.
But it is not reloading because of “self.netUtil.callWebservice(urlStr) {(data)” i presume.

My code is below
—————————————

```
     if netUtil.isConnectedToNetwork() == true
    {
        self.showActivityIndicator(self.view,message: "Synch is progress...")

            //Logic toc all Web Service
            var urlStr: String = "\(constants.SERVER_URL)"
            self.container.addSubview(self.lblProcess)
            self.netUtil.callWebservice(urlStr) {(data) -> Void in

            self.fileMgr.createFileDirectory("/Surveyor")
            self.filePath = self.fileMgr.createFile(self.fileMgr.getSurveyourPropListXmlName(""))

            self.fileMgr.writeFile(data, filenamePath: self.fileMgr.getSurveyourPropListXmlName(""))
            self.xmlNSData = data.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!

            self.beginParsing()
            self.loadPropertyMap()
            var unitCount = 0


                for Prop: Property in self.properties
                {

                    unitCount++

                    for view in self.view.subviews
                    {
                        if view is UILabel
                        {
                            view.removeFromSuperview()
                        }
                    }

                    /* refresh label code start here */
                     dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
                        //Run UI Updates
                         self.unitCount++
                         println("unitCount \( self.unitCount)")
                        var totCount = self.properties.count
                        var message = "Synchronization \(self.unitCount)/\(totCount) buildings completed"
                        self.lblProcess.text = message
                        self.lblProcess.setNeedsDisplay()

                    })

                    /* refresh label code End here */

                    //Backup code to be shfted while pushing in web service
                    self.fileMgr.getSurveyorUnitFiles("", proCode: Prop.proCode as String, isCreateBackup: true)

                    //back up code ended
                    self.callUnitsWebservice(Prop.proCode as String)  //another web service cal

                }
             self.lblProcess.removeFromSuperview()

            self.hideActivityIndicator()
        }
```

### OUTput for println attached

properties count > 10
unitCount 1
unitCount 2
unitCount 3
unitCount 4
unitCount 5
unitCount 6
unitCount 7
unitCount 8
unitCount 9
unitCount 10

If i am putting the label out of the loop than it is reloading…
  What should i do reload label in the loop so that it changes when each loop gets excited?

Thanks for the help in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can only refresh UI from the main thread.

The `self.netUtil.callWebservice(urlStr) {(data) -> Void in}` runs as a block, which is not in the main thread.

You have to do something like this within the block:

```
        //Logic synchronization all Web Service
        var urlStr: String = "\(constants.SERVER_URL)"

        //Add the view. Don't forget to remove it when the looping is done.
        self.container.addSubview(self.lblProcess)

        self.netUtil.callWebservice(urlStr) {(data) -> Void in    //I suspect this method to reason why my label is not refreshing

        self.beginParsing()
        var unitCount = 0

        for Prop: Property in self.properties
        {

             unitCount++

            for view in self.view.subviews
            {
                if view is UILabel
                {
                    view.removeFromSuperview()
                }
            }

            /* refresh label code start here */
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
                    //Run UI Updates
                    var totCount = self.properties.count
                    var message = "Synchronization \(unitCount)/\(totCount) buildings completed"
                    self.lblProcess.text = message
                    self.lblProcess.setNeedsDisplay()
            })
            /* refresh label code End here */

            //Backup code to be shfted while pushing in web service
            self.fileMgr.getSurveyorUnitFiles("", proCode: Prop.proCode as String, isCreateBackup: true)

            //back up code ended
            self.callUnitsWebservice(Prop.proCode as String)  //another web service cal

        }

        self.hideActivityIndicator()
    }
```

Comment: ...it is updating only one time..in the loop..i want to update counter eachtime loop calls

Comment: Zhi-Wei Cai, What should be done to avoid this issue?

Comment: wrapping those code that do the UI changing as in my answer. And as I can see, you have an `addSubview` which should have been done once? If so it should be somewhere outside the loop.

Comment: Zhi-Wei Cai, thanks for quick reply...but it does refresh only one time..I have updated my code in question..

Comment: Can you try putting a `print()` to log the loop counter and see in which loop did it stopped? Also, `unitCount` is not accessible in the block either unless it's a global afaicr.

Comment: Zhi-Wei Cai, i did that println unitcount is coming 10 but refreshing the label only ones..i have attached the output in questions..Please have a look

Comment: Do you mind to set up a sample project so I can see it directly?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82186/discussion-between-dhaval-shah-and-zhi-wei-cai).